# What if I want to ask the same question for both C++98 and C++11

Tags: discussion

What if I want to ask the same question for both C++98 and C++11 and the answer strongly depends on 98 vs 11?

Since there would be two very distinct but correct answers should I open two questions? Would it be reasonable to open a question that roughly says "exactly that question but now using only C++98"?

Comment: Having a tag with both `C++` and `C++11`, or whatever the tag is, does not indicate the answer has to incorporate both. There are a handful of questions tagged `C++` and `java` that obviously don't require both to be implemented simultaneously. It may be a comparison between languages, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.  Although I wouldn't copy the C++11 question wholesale.  You should always use your own wording.

Because the answers for C++11 are insufficient/incompatible/poor/etc. for C++98, you are not asking a repeat of the original question.  Duplicate questions are only duplicates when they *ask the same thing* and can be *solved in the same way*.  Because the C++11 answers do not solve the problem for C++98, they are not answers to the C++98 question.  So, the two may be considered separate questions.

If you want to be especially clear, include a link to the C++11 question and explain why it does not work for you.  That way, people cannot mistakenly think it is a duplicate.

The only time you should not ask separate questions for different versions of a language is when the answers are the same for both versions.  In other words, the language did not change enough to alter the behavior of feature X.

Comment: Just a comment: Even if the old way still works, it might be severely sub-optimal and/or dangerous.